# Solving Lagrange multipliers system

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I need help solving this system:

$$
\begin{cases} 2(x-1) = \lambda2x \\ 2(y-2) = \lambda2y  \\ 2(z-2) = \lambda2z \\x^2 + y^2+z^2 = 1 \end{cases}
$$

I can find $$ \lambda = (x-1)/x $$ but can't go further.

Any help?

Comment: Your first equation suggests that $\lambda=(x-1)/x$.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Second equation is $2(y-2)= \lambda 2y$?

Comment: Yes. Again, my mistake.

Comment: We have $(2\lambda - 2)x = -2$, so $x = -1/(\lambda - 1)$. Do the same for $y$ and $z$ from the other two equations. Then the last equation will give you $\lambda$, hence the others $x$, $y$ and $z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First three equations lead to:

$$\lambda = \frac{x-1}{x} = \frac{y-2}{y} = \frac{z-2}{z}.$$

Now subtracting 1 on every term implies

$$\lambda-1 = -\frac{1}{x} = -\frac{2}{y} = -\frac{2}{z}.$$

Now you found a relation of $x,y$ and $z$:
$$
2x = y = z.
$$
I believe you can take it from here.